# VBA Exporting a huge collection into .csv file

Tags: excel, csv, file-io, vba

I am quite new to VBA and I could not find a function to export a huge collection i am creating during a simulation into .csv file.

I have found a solution which suggests converting collection into array then writing in excel workbook. I successfully open a wb, convert things into array and then write. Yet this takes a long time for my collection.

I am expecting something like as from R:
write.csv().

Comment: There is not such a function to write directly from a collection to a .csv file in VBA.  Please post the relevant parts of your code. Please read the HELP pages for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask); and also [How to Provide an Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very short example:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim c As Collection
    Set c = New Collection

    c.Add "Larry,Moe,Curly"
    c.Add "Columbia,Magenta"
    c.Add "Winken,Blink,Nod"

    Close #1
    Open "C:\TestFolder\TestFile.csv" For Output As #1
    For i = 1 To c.Count
        Print #1, c.Item(i)
    Next i
    Close #1
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works like magic. I could not think of it as I am new to VBA. @Gary's Student